# netlogo programing help on traffic simulation

Tags: simulation, traffic, netlogo

I am trying to find if there is a turtle on `patch-ahead n`

whose speed - acceleration is <= 0. The code I came up with is:

```
if any? turtles on patch-ahead n with [speed <= (speed - acceleration)]
```

but this gives an error that:

> patch-ahead expects a number, instead got agent set.

How do I remedy this?

*n* is a number variable. I want to access the turtle's 'speed', which is a user defined turtle-own variable, at the *n*th patch from the calling turtle. The command '`with`' doesn't work here. Please suggest an alternative to access the speed of the turtle at, say, the 3rd patch from the calling turtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [patch-ahead documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#patch-ahead) you will notice that it does require one argument: a number representing the distance to look ahead. You are using a patch 'n' instead of a number.

As per you comment, I think maybe you want turtles-on, and use parenthesis to make it clearer, as such:

```
if any? ((turtles-on patch-ahead n) with [speed <= (speed - aceleration)])
```

In the above I am assuming that `n` is a number: the distance you want to look ahead.

Comment: n is a number variable. i want to excess the speed (speed is user defined variable of turtle) of the turtle at nth patch from the calling turtle. the command 'with' doesnt work here, please suggest any alternative to excess the speed of the turtle at, say, 3rd patch from the calling turtle.

Comment: I updated the answer. Note that its 'turtles-on' and not 'turtles on'.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of this, but you are looking "n" spaces ahead which means you have selected a **single patch**.  This probably needs to be in a loop from 1 to n to check all of the patches in between.  Just wanted to make sure that is clear